# foreach: invalid conversion from 'QGraphicsItem*' to 'QGraphicsItemGroup*

Tags: c++, qt

I am implementing copy operation in graphicsView for different entities such as point, ellipse, circle etc. in qt but getting an error

```
 error: invalid conversion from 'QGraphicsItem*' to 'QGraphicsItemGroup*
```

My code to copy operation in cadgraphicsview.cpp is:

```
void CadGraphicsScene::copy()
{
    selectedItems.clear();
    foreach(QGraphicsItemGroup *item, itemList){
        QString str;
        if (item->isSelected())
        {
            if(item->type() == Point::Type)
            {
                Point *pointItem = (Point *) item;
                str = QString("Point %1 %2 ")
                        .arg(pointItem->scenePos().x())
                        .arg(pointItem->scenePos().y());

            }

            }
            }
    }
```

In cadgraphicsscene.h

```
#ifndef CADGRAPHICSSCENE_H
#define CADGRAPHICSSCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QXmlStreamWriter>
#include <QUndoStack>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QFrame>

#include "cadcommandadd.h"
#include "cadcommanddelete.h"
#include "cadcommandmove.h"


class CadGraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CadGraphicsScene(QObject *parent, QUndoStack *);
    enum Mode { NoMode, PointMode, LineMode, CircleMode, EllipseMode, TextMode };

    QFont font() const
    {
        return myFont;
    }

    QColor textColor() const
    {
        return myTextColor;
    }

    void setTextColor(const QColor &color);
    void setFont(const QFont &font);
    void deleteItems();
    void writeStream(QXmlStreamWriter *stream);
    void readStream(QXmlStreamReader *stream);


public slots:
    void setMode(Mode mode);
    void selectItems();
    void editorLostFocus(mText *item);
    void cut();
    void copy();
    void paste();
    void del();
protected:
     void contentsContextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event);
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent);
    void setFlags();
    void areItemsSelectable(bool);
    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event);
    void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
signals:
    void textInserted(QGraphicsTextItem *item);
    void itemSelected(QGraphicsItem *item);

private:
    Mode entityMode;
    QUndoStack *mUndoStack;

    bool mFirstClick;
    bool mSecondClick;
    bool mThirdClick;
    bool mPaintFlag;
    QVector<QPointF> stuff;
    QPointF start_p, mid_p, end_p, move_p, check_p;
    QPen paintpen, linePen;

    QList<QGraphicsItem *> itemList;
    Point *pointItem;
    Line *lineItem;
    Circle *circleItem;
    Ellipse *ellipseItem;
    mText *textItem;
    QColor myTextColor;
    QFont myFont;

    typedef QPair<QGraphicsItem *, QPointF> itemPos;
    QList<itemPos> selectedItems;
private:
    QAction *cutAct;
    QAction *copyAct;
    QAction *pasteAct;
};

#endif // CADGRAPHICSSCENE_H
```

Help me out to sought this :)

Comment: What do `entityMode`, `mUndoStack`, `contentsContextMenuEvent`, etc. have to do with the question?  Check out [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/) and ["Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the best way to get focused help on the Internet with a programming question.

Comment: `itemList` is declared as `QList<QGraphicsItem *>`. You write `foreach(QGraphicsItemGroup *item, itemList)`. The compiler says that it can't cast `QGraphicsItem*` to `QGraphicsItemGroup*`. What additional information do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `itemList` as:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem *> itemList;
```

You are then trying to iterate it with:

```
foreach(QGraphicsItemGroup *item, itemList){
   // ...
}
```

From the documentation you can see that [QGraphicsItemGroup inherits from QGraphicsItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsitemgroup.html#details).  So every QGraphicsItemGroup "is a" QGraphicsItem.  But not every QGraphicsItem "is a" QGraphicsItemGroup.

If you want to iterate that itemList then item will have to be a QGraphicsItem, or itemList will have to be a QGraphicsItemGroup.  It seems that since you are testing for specific classes then the former is probably what you want.